# Adding level 1 time-varying predictor makes mixed effects model non-linear

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, growth-model

I am new to mixed effects modelling and I am trying to predict depression from physical activity using mixed effects modelling / multi-level modelling. The data consists of timepoints in months (7 months), so each month there is a different value for depression and physical activity (below). When adding activity as the time-varying predictor, the model predictions become non-linear. Is this supposed to happen?

```
   country Month depression  activity
1       20     0  -6.552636  0.000000
2       20     1  -5.499386  0.000000
3       20     2  -6.766055 10.129032
4       20     3  -5.396426 17.000000
5       20     4  -3.647919 17.000000
6       20     5  -4.616490 16.466667
7       20     6  -3.686440 16.000000
8        3     0  -7.449156  0.000000
9        3     1  -4.847658  0.000000
10       3     2  -7.860457  7.387097
11       3     3  -6.819432 15.000000
12       3     4  -5.227588 15.000000
13       3     5  -4.867199 14.700000
14       3     6  -3.627923 14.000000
```

Below is my model specification in r nlme:

```
# basic growth model to account for effects of time
model = lme(depression ~ Month, random=~1|country, data=df, method='ML', na.action=na.exclude) 

# adding activity as a time-varying predictor
model2 = lme(depression ~ Month + activity, random=~1|country, data=df, method='ML', na.action=na.exclude)
```

Results:

```
summary(model2)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
 Data: df 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  709.7921 724.5003 -349.8961

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | country
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.615538 2.692369

Fixed effects: depression ~ Month + activity 
                Value Std.Error  DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept) -8.067505 0.5647178 118 -14.285905       0
Month        1.016504 0.1451743 118   7.001952       0
activity    -0.295092 0.0507493 118  -5.814699       0
 Correlation: 
         (Intr) Month 
Month    -0.358       
activity -0.206 -0.610

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-4.0076454 -0.4664691  0.0966998  0.5998769  1.9300630 

Number of Observations: 140
Number of Groups: 20
```

Predictions from model1 and model2:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(model = predict(model), model2 = predict(model2))
df %>% filter(country %in% c(20,19,18,17)) %>% 
       ggplot(aes(x=Month, y=depression)) + 
       geom_point(aes(color=country)) + 
       geom_line(aes(y=model2, color=country)) + 
       geom_line(aes(y=model, color=country), linetype='longdash') + 
       facet_wrap(~ country, ncol=2)
```

[image]

The dashed line is prediction from model1 and solid line is the predictions from model2 (with activity as time-varying predictor). My question is:

1. Does adding a level 1 time-varying predictor make the model non-linear?'
2. Can I interpret the coefficient for activity the same way as a linear model? Meaning 1 unit increase in activity is associated with a decrease in -0.295 unit decrease in depression?

Comment: Why do you think the model is non linear ?  and plesse include the code you used to create the plots

Comment: The predictions from model 1 (dashed lines) are linear (straight line) while those from model 2 are not. Does this imply non-linearity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does adding a level 1 time-varying predictor make the model non-linear?'

No, the model is a linear model - this means that it is linear in the parameters. Of course, it is perfectly normal to model non-linear associations with a linear model. There is no reason to expect that the predictions will lie on a straight line after you introduce another variable.

> Can I interpret the coefficient for activity the same way as a linear model? Meaning 1 unit increase in activity is associated with a decrease in -0.295 unit decrease in depression?

Yes, *while leaving the other variable unchanged*.